# How to set default browser to Internet Explorer in R?

Tags: r, windows, internet-explorer

I am rarely using IE for web browsing, so would like R help opens in it when calling help functions. Currently it opens my default web browser (Chrome). I would like to leave system-wide default browser intact, but change browser only for R.

Is it possible?

I found some texts about how to edit `Rprofile.site`, but failed to deduce how to set for IE and Windows.

Comment: You need to set `options(browser=ie)` in `Rprofile.site` file or something approaching (I don't have Windows), i.e the complete path to Internet Explorer.

Comment: But why?  Doesn't your help page show up in  a new window? It's not like you're going  to  save on  memory or CPU or anything.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A solution could be to create a file named `.Rprofile` in your home directory and put the following line:

```
 options(browser="path/to/IE")
```

Of course, you have to replace the `path/to/IE` part to the actual path to the IE executable (could be something like `C:\\Program Files\\Internet Explorer\\iexplore.exe\`).

Restart R and try for instance `browseURL("https://www.google.com")` to see if it has taken effect.